# Subscript (" [ ] ")operator gives strange errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, operator-overloading, constants

I am getting some strange behaviour from visual studio, regarding the following code snippet, The error list shows several instances of E0349: no operator"[]" matches these operands.

Intellisense seems to be implying a type mismatch, but as you will see in the code, there is no type mismatch.

To begin, I have defined a Vec4 struct for the purposes of making a mat4:
(I have only included the pertinent functions)

```
struct Vec4f
{
    union
    {
        struct { float x, y, z, w; };
        struct { float r, g, b, a; };
    };
    // copy constructor
    Vec4f(Vec4f const & v) :
        x(v.x),
        y(v.y),
        z(v.z),
        w(v.w)
    {

    }
    // Operators
    float & operator[](int index)
    {
        assert(index > -1 && index < 4);
        return (&x)[index];
    }

    Vec4f & operator=(Vec4f const & v)
    {
        // If I use: "this->x = v[0];" as above, E0349
        this->x = v.x;
        this->y = v.y;
        this->z = v.z;
        this->w = v.w;
        return *this;
    }    
}
```

Using the above Vec4 class, I have created a 4x4 matrix:

```
struct Mat4f
{
    //storage for matrix values
    Vec4f value[4];

    //copy constructor
    Mat4f(const Mat4f& m)
    {
        value[0] = m[0]; // calling m[0] causes E0349
        value[1] = m[1];
        value[2] = m[2];
        value[2] = m[3];
    }

    inline Vec4f & operator[](const int index)
    {
        assert(index > -1 && index < 4);
        return this->value[index];
    }
}
```

When any of the "[]" operators are called, I end up with this E0349 error, and I do not understand the problem. Oddly, the file compiles just fine. I have tried deleting the hidden ".suo" file as suggested in an answer to a different question, but to no avail. I would appreciate this explained to me.

Comment: The expression `-1< index < 4` is equal to `(-1< index) < 4` and will always be `true`. It will always be `true` because `-1 < index` will be either false (which can be converted to the integer `0`) or true (which can be converted to the integer `1`). The integers `0` and `1` are indeed less than `4`. And note that `assert` is a macro that might be "disabled" in release builds.

Comment: You also break strict aliasing by pretending `&x` is an array of `float` values, which it is not! That leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  No worries I'll change that. Thanks. Curiously, This is basically a non template version of the GLM library, which does exactly that (not the assert though).]

Comment: It's also worth highlighting that a union can only support reading data which was the last assigned - ie if you have at any point the assigning of vec4.r/g/b/a and then copy it you'll have UB too

Comment: @UKMonkey Again, this is code pulled straight from GLM (with modifications to make it non template). It's for personal use, and it's not a use case I've ever come across, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @IanYoung: It doesn't matter really where the code comes from. Broken code is broken regardless of who wrote it. Fix: `switch(index) { case 0: return x; case 1: return y; case 2: return z; case 3: return w;}` and rely on the optimizer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Mat4f::operator[]` is a non-const member function, which can't be called on the argument `m` of `Mat4f::Mat4f`, it's declared as `const & Mat4f`.

You could add another `const` overloading, which could be called on constants. e.g.

```
inline Vec4f const & operator[](const int index) const
//           ~~~~~                               ~~~~~
{
    assert(-1 < index && index < 4); // As @Someprogrammerdude commented, assert(-1 < index < 4) doesn't do what you expect
    return this->value[index];
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but what if I wish to modify the contents of the matrix by use of that same operator?

Comment: @IanYoung Overlaod resolution works; const version called on const Mat4f; non-const version called on non-const Mat4f.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. It never occurred to me that my const correctness was, well, incorrect. Thank you.